# Install a Nuget package ignoring ONE dependency

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, nuget

I'm sure this has been asked before, but I spent almost an hour searchin Stackoverflow and haven't found any answer. Sorry if I missed it.

**I need to install a Nuget package without one (just one) of its dependencies.**

In particular, I'm adding SignalR to an ASP.NET MVC app and I need to skip jQuery-dependency because I already have it added manually, from a CDN-hosting. Don't need it in my project.

But I need all the other dependencies, and I need them managed by Nuget, not manually. So if the author adds some new dependency to the next version, - like Owin or something, - it will be pulled in automatically.

The only solution I came up with is to install the package with all the dependencies and then run

```
Uninstall-Package jQuery -Force
```

Is this ok? It seems a bit "hacky" to me, or is it fine? Are there any other options?

Comment: Why not just install `Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.SystemWeb`? That's a dependency of `Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR`, which I think is just a helper package to include the dependencies.

Comment: @mason I still need the client-side JS scripts for SignalR

Comment: @jitbit, what about this issue? Would you please let me know the latest information about this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing is install jQuery nuget package **and then simply remove files from the `/Scripts` directory**

Now all the jQuery-dependent packages are happy and my project is not bloated with unneeded files

Answer (score 0):

> I need to install a Nuget package without one (just one) of its
>   dependencies.

Not possible currently through Command Line, because Install-Package doesn't have any parameter to skip a particular dependency (as visible in the latest microsoft docs reference).

---

Use the below command if you want to avoid all of the Dependencies (as you can't skip a particular dependency because it is nowhere quoted in Microsoft Docs):

`Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR -IgnoreDependencies`

Detail about the parameter from [Install-Package document from Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/tools/powershell-reference#install-package):

```
Install-Package [-Id] <string> [-Version <string>] [-IgnoreDependencies] 
[-ProjectName <string>]  [-Source <string>] [-IncludePrerelease] [-FileConflictAction] 
[-DependencyVersion <dependencyVersion>] [-WhatIf]
```

`IgnoreDependencies` : Installs only this package and not its dependencies

Comment: I know about -IgnoreDependencies, I specifically asked about *removing ONE dependency* and keeping all the rest managed by Nuget.

Comment: @jitbit - Already answered, you can't. It is nowhere mentioned in the docs, and no such parameter is visible. SORRY, but currently you can't achieve that.

Comment: @am-i-helpful how about the solution I included into the question itself? Sounds like I can remove one dependency

Comment: @jitbit - YEAH, obviously that is a hacky solution as you mentioned in your last line of the question, :)

Comment: Why is it hacky and `-IgnoreDependencies` is not?

Comment: @jitbit - Because `-IgnoreDependencies` **ignores all the dependencies** in your case, but, you require only 1 dependency to be ignored, which your solution is a smart way to achieve.

Comment: @jitbit - Though it doesn't help you with what you want to achieve, but, the answer is what it is. Shall I assume that this answer is fit for this question, can be accepted, or shall I delete the answer altogether?

Answer (score 0):

> Is this ok? It seems a bit "hacky" to me, or is it fine? Are there any other options?

The simple answer is "**It depends on the version of jQuery-dependency which you have added manually** ".

You will notice that the dependency restrictions of Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR is: `jQuery (>= 1.6.4)`:

[image]

So if the version of jQuery which you have installed manually is higher than the version of dependency restrictions of `Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR`, you can uninstall the jQuery, then install the package `Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR`. Therefore, your method is feasible.

**Note**: After install the package `Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR`, you can update the version of the package jQuery, if you want.

In contrast, the version of jQuery which you have installed manually is lower than 1.6.4 and you do not want to use the high version of that package, you can not do it with your method, otherwise, NuGet will install the jQuery with version 1.6.4 after install the package `Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR`.